# From MS Access VBA close encrypted excel after failed password

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm keeping an ID for API in an encrypted excel file (open to alternative suggestions) and using Microsoft access VBA to open the encrypted excel and extract the ID.

The issue is that it will not close excel if the password is incorrect. This code works fine if you enter the password correctly

```
Public Function getDeploymentID() As String
Dim fileLocation As String
fileLocation = "___DeploymentID.xlsx"
Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

On Error GoTo getDeploymentID_ERROR
MsgBox "The development password is in a password protected excel. It will prompt you for the password next"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileLocation, True)
'User must enter password to continue. If they don't it'll error out on above line
DoEvents

'Get deploymentID
getDeploymentID = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

'Close it
'wb.Close               'will close workbook, won't close excel
wb.Application.Quit     'will close workbook and excel
DoEvents
GoTo getDeploymentID_Cleanup

getDeploymentID_ERROR:
Debug.Print "Failed to open DeploymentID excel file. Error " & err.Number & ":" & err.description
objExcel.Quit           'THIS IS NOT WORKING
DoEvents

getDeploymentID_Cleanup:
Set wb = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The error appears even if the correct password will be entered... But `Workbooks` does not exist in `Access` Application. See the bellow answer to understand how you must properly access the object in discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to access the `Workbooks` collection through the `objExcel`.

```
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation, True)
```

Then,

```
wb.Close 'close workbook
objExcel.Quit 'quit excel app
```

References:

- [Workbook.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close)
- [Application.Quit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.quit)

---

Regarding the structure of the function, I would add the error handling at the bottom and call `Resume` to avoid the 2nd `GoTo` statement.

```
'...
On Error GoTo getDeploymentID_ERROR
'...

'Get deploymentID
 getDeploymentID = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

getDeploymentID_Cleanup:
    wb.Close
    objExcel.Quit
    Exit Function

getDeploymentID_ERROR:
    Debug.Print "Failed to open DeploymentID excel file. Error " & err.Number & ":" & err.description
    Resume getDeploymentID_Cleanup
End Function
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Also, thanks for the notice about resume, learned something new